# Map custom database value function in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a simple database function, which expects two strings as parameter and returns a string. I want to map this with entity framework. Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45451383/dbfunction-cannot-be-translated-into-a-linq-to-entities-store-expression), I've created a simple function header:

```
[DbFunction("dbo", "StripCharacters")]
public static string StripCharacters(string input, string pattern = "^A-Z0-9") => throw new NotSupportedException();
```

Like in the linked post, I get the same error message, as soon as I try to use this method inside one of my queries. The exception message is:

> Method `System.String StripCharacters(System.String, System.String)` in type `DE.ZA.TrailerLoadingAssistant.Web.Models.DatabaseEntities` cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression

```
await mapi.db.TrailerAutocompleteHelpers
    .Where(t => t.SearchString.Contains(DatabaseEntities.StripCharacters(userInput, "^A-Z0-9")))
    .ToListAsync();
```

Here's the database function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[StripCharacters]
(
    @String NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @MatchExpression VARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX) WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    SET @MatchExpression =  '%['+@MatchExpression+']%'

    WHILE PatIndex(@MatchExpression, @String) > 0
        SET @String = Stuff(@String, PatIndex(@MatchExpression, @String), 1, '')

    RETURN @String

END
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually made two mistakes. First off, you must add a function declaration to your EDMX file by hand:

```
<Function Name="StripCharacters" ReturnType="nvarchar" Schema="dbo" >
  <Parameter Name="String" Mode="In" Type="nvarchar" />
  <Parameter Name="MatchExpression" Mode="In" Type="varchar" />
</Function>
```

Secondly, the first parameter of the `DbFunction` attribute must not be the schema name of your database, but the Entity Framework model namespace. This can be found in the EDMX file again:

```
<Schema Namespace="MyApplicationModel.Store" ...>
```

The correct attribute would be:

```
[DbFunction("MyApplicationModel.Store", "StripCharacters")]
```